# How can I be able to start Windows 7 from Ubuntu, and not from grub?

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, windows-7, uninstall, system

While I was in Windows 7, I once changed my System Settings to have Ubuntu starting automatically, and since then I don't know how to run Windows again (what a stupid thing I did). Since I can't run Windows, I'm unable to uninstall Ubuntu, which I have installed *inside Windows*, as Wubi.
Please let me know if there is anyway I can solve this problem.

I'm using Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Try F8 at boot?

Answer (score -1):

Install grub. It is the only way possible to recover it *strictly* from Ubuntu. Other methods are possible but GRUB is the easiest. It is very simple to install as well.

Right from Ubuntu's support pages:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX  # Example: sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

If you later wish to return to the Windows Boot Loader, it is possible and there are many guides on the internet. I would highly recommend that you install your own partitioned and completely seperate Ubuntu. It works much more elegantly.

Comment: It's a wubi install - this doesn't work. Luckily if you run that command from a Wubi install it will ignore it.